# Boosting the tuple in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine

I have an apparel data in Elasticsearch document as below. It contains product name, color and material information

```
/products/data
{
   product_name: "xxxxxx",
   color: "C1",
   material: "M1"
},
{
   product_name: "yyyyyy",
   color: "C2",
   material: "M2"
},
{
   product_name: "zzzzzz",
   color: "C1",
   material: "M2"
}...
```

Now I want to fetch the `10` products with `color: C1` and `material: M2`. If there are no sufficient products in that combination I want to fetch the products with `color: C1` and `material: M1`. I will be having the combination of `color` and `material`. In this example, I have the highest priority to the combination `C1, M2`, second highest is `C1, M1`, then it may be `C2, M3` and so on. Based on the priority I want to Boost the result (in single query). Is that possible in Elasticsearch?

I'm expecting the returned document to be as below

```
    {
       _score: highest_score,
       product_name: "xxxxxx",
       color: "C1",
       material: "M2"
    },
    {
       _score: sencond_highest
       product_name: "yyyyyy",
       color: "C1",
       material: "M1"
    },
    {
       _score: third_highest
       product_name: "zzzzzz",
       color: "C2",
       material: "M3"
    }
```

Sample dataset to reproduce the issue

```
 POST mat/product
    {
     "pname": "prod1",
     "color": "c1",
     "material": "m1"
    }
    POST mat/product
    {
     "pname": "prod2",
     "color": "c2",
     "material": "m2"
    }
    POST mat/product
    {
     "pname": "prod3",
     "color": "c3",
     "material": "m3"
    }
    POST mat/product
    {
     "pname": "prod4",
     "color": "c1",
     "material": "m2"
    }
    POST mat/product
    {
     "pname": "prod5",
     "color": "c2",
     "material": "m2"
    }
    POST mat/product
    {
     "pname": "prod6",
     "color": "c3",
     "material": "m3"
    }

  GET mat/product/_search
  {
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "minimum_should_match":1,
      "should":[
        {"bool":{
          "boost":181,
          "must":[{"match":{"color":"c3"}},{"match":{"material":"m3"}}]
        }},
        {"bool":{
          "boost":180,
          "must":[{"match":{"color":"c2"}},{"match":{"material":"m2"}}]
        }},
        {"bool":{
          "boost":179,
          "must":[{"match":{"color":"c1"}},{"match":{"material":"m2"}}]
        }}
]}},"size":10}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `bool/should` queries in order to give a different boost to different material/color pairs.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "boost": 4,
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "color": {
                    "value": "C1"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "material": {
                    "value": "M1"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "boost": 2,
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "color": {
                    "value": "C1"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "material": {
                    "value": "M2"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "boost": 1,
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "color": {
                    "value": "C2"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "material": {
                    "value": "M3"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not what I wanted. I want to boost the combination. Like "C1, M1" or "C1, M2" or "C2, M3" and so on. Here "C1, M1" highest priority and  "C2, M3" is lowest.

Comment: Im not able to get the result as expected. Score is not according to the boost I gave. Sometimes the combination "C1,M1" will be having highest score than the combination "C1,M2". Even though  I have given highest boost value to "C1,M2"

Comment: Provide a gist so I can reproduce your issue locally and investigate.

Comment: you don't have any material constraint in your query

Comment: Added material too